# How generate a new div row per 3-4 colums of data

Tags: php, html, css, loops

I know this question has been made a lot before, but I still don't get it to work. I'm trying to add each post I make to display side by side each 3-4 columns. Right now, I have something like this: [image]

but I would like to have them side by side, something like this

[image]

(image was from someones previous question). Here is a snippet of my code from where this is coming

```
<div>
            <?php
            global $connection;
            $nRows = $connection->query("SELECT * 
                                                   FROM posts
                                                   ORDER BY post_id DESC");
            if($nRows->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($row = $nRows->fetch()) {
                    $post_title = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['post_title']);
                    $post_author = $ed->encrypt_decrypt('decrypt',$row['post_author']);
                    $post_file = $row['post_file'];
                    $post_date = $row['post_time'];
                    ?>
                    <!-- Blog Content BEGIN Display-->
                    <div class="column">
                        <h2>
                            <!-- This redirects you to a specific post -->
                            <a href="post/postFetch/fetchByTitle/fetchByPT.php?post_id=<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>&post_title=<?php echo $row['post_title'];?>" class="link-post-title" style="font-family: Arial"><?php echo "#".$row['post_id'] . " ". $post_title;?></a>
                        </h2>

                        <p class="lead" style="font-family: FontAwesome">
                            <!-- This redirects you to the post author -->
                            &#xf21b; <a href="post/postFetch/fetchByAuthor/fetchByPA.php?post_author=<?php echo $row['post_author'];?>" class="link-post-author" style="font-family: Arial"><?php echo $post_author;?> </a> <?php //echo ' ' . '#' . str_replace(',', '#', $row['post_tags']);?>
                        </p>

                        <!-- if there is no image, just remove the entire div --><?php
                        $file_parts = pathinfo($post_file);
                        if(isset($file_parts['extension'])){
                            switch ($file_parts['extension']){
                                case "jpg":
                                    if(!empty($post_file)) { ?>
                                        <div class="imgBox">
                                             <img src="post/postFiles/<?php echo $post_file;?>">
                                        </div><?php
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "mp4":?>
                                    <div class="vidBox">
                                         <video width="615" height="315" controls>
                                             <source src="post/postFiles/<?php echo $post_file;?>">
                                         </video>
                                    </div><?php
                                    break;
                                case "": // Handle file extension for files ending in '.'
                                case NULL: // Handle no file extension
                                    break;
                            }
                        }?>
                        <p style="font-family: Arial"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php
                            echo "Posted on " . $post_date;?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Blog Content END Display --><?php
                }
            } else { ?>
                <p style="color: darkgoldenrod" class="mssgAlign"><u>NO RECORDS</u></p><?php
            }
            $nRows = null;
            }?>
        </div>
```

I'm not using Bootstrap. Maybe this is my error and I should start doing this, but in the meantime, I'll continue how I'm going. Any help/tip is welcomed

Comment: Your problem is not with PHP, I suggest creating that page with dummy data in pure HTML and after you are certain your html code is working fine, then add your PHP code. to answer your problem, you might want to use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap group of every 4 columns (div with content) inside wrapper (parent div) and style columns to display inline-block.

```
<?php
$break = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++)
{   
    if($break % 4 === 0)
    {
        echo '<br>open div<br/>'; //your wrapper/row start
    }

    $break++;

    echo $i . ' '; //your column with content

    if($break % 4 === 0)
    {
        echo '<br />close div<br />'; //your wrapper/row end
    }   
}
```